# Stationary distribution of a positive recurrent random walk

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

There is a non-negative random walk {0,1,2,3,...}.
I got a matrix like this:
\begin{bmatrix} 
 \frac23     & \frac13    &  0 & 0     &  ... \\
 p_i,_{i-1}  & p_i,_i  & p_i,_{i+1}  &  0    &  0 & ...  \\
   0   & p_i,_{i-1}  & p_i,_i  & p_i,_{i+1}   & 0 & ...  \\
   0  &   0   & p_i,_{i-1}  &  p_i,_i    & p_i,_{i+1} & 0 & ...  \\
   0  &   0   & 0  &  p_i,_{i-1}    & p_i,_i & p_i,_{i+1} & 0 & ...  \\
\ddots     & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots     & \ddots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}

How to calculate the stationary distribution of it knowing that it's positive recurrent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p_{i,i+1}=p_i$, $p_{i,i}=r_i$, $p_{i,i-1}=q_i$ to simplify the notation slightly. (Then $p_0 = \frac13$). Note that of course $p_i+r_i+q_i=1$ for this to be an (infinite) stochastic matrix. We want to find an invariant measure $\nu$ such that $\nu P=\nu$. Set $\nu(0) = 1$ and for any $k>0$, $$\nu(k) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_{i-1}}{q_i}. $$
Note that
$$
\nu(0) = \nu(0)r_0 + \nu(1)q_1 = r_0+p_0 = 1 = \nu(0),
$$
and for $k>0$,
\begin{align}
\nu(k) &= \nu(k-1)p_{k-1} + \nu(k)r_k + \nu(k+1)q_{k+1}\\
&= \nu(k)\left(\frac{q_k}{p_{k-1}}p_{k-1} + r_k + \frac{p_k}{q_{k+1}}q_{k+1} \right)\\
&=\nu(k).
\end{align}
Now let $C=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \nu(k)$. Then $\pi = \frac1C\nu$ satisfies $\pi P=\pi$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \pi(k)=1$, so that $\pi$ is a stationary distribution for $P$. Note that $C$ is finite precisely because the Markov chain is positive recurrent.